# HashMap пробежатся по элементам с индекса по индекс

Tags: java

Есть `HashMap<String, String>` требуется пробежатся по нему получая имя, значение. Но пробежатся по индексам 56 по 70, в случае выхода за пределы выдать исключение.

Comment: Можете подробнее рассказать, что вы хотите сделать? `HashMap` в принципе не гарантирует порядок, и говорить про индексы в нем странно.

Comment: Да я уже понел что это не сделаешь по индексово, придумал как реализовать это на ArrayList с кешированием индексов и их обновлении при надобности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть две проблемы: `HashMap` не поддерживает индексированный доступ, а также не гарантирует возвращение записей в том же порядке, в котором их добавляли. Поэтому считывание определенных индексов не имеет особого смысла.

В то же время есть `LinkedHashMap`, который гарантирует порядок записей, но по-прежнему не имеет индексированного доступа. Поэтому придется проитерировать всю коллекцию, одновременно ведя учет количества пройденных элементов и проверяя, не завершилась ли коллекция. Попробуйте написать этот код сами, если возникнут сложности, обновите вопрос.